# Pass struct member to function pointer in same struct in C

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I need to pass a struct member such as "str" in the following example as an argument to a function pointer in same struct such as "(ToUpper)", or by another words I need to access the value of "str" inside the "ToUpper" function.

```
typedef struct _String {
            char* str;
            char* (*ToUpper) (void);
         } String;
```

Can I do it in this way ?

Comment: C does not support OOP. A pointer is not an active entity you can "pass" something to.

Comment: Note that you should never use identifiers beginning with an underscore and a capital, identifiers that contain double underscores, and (at global scope) identifiers beginning with an underscore. All of these are reserved for the standard library's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no `this` pointer in C, you have to pass a reference to whatever object you're manipulating when working with function pointers in structs...

```
typedef struct _String {
    char* str;
    char* (*ToUpper)( struct _String );
} String;
```

Then you should have an "initialize" function that is like this..

```
char* ToUpper( struct _String s ) {
   // ...
}

String newString(char* str) {
    return (String) { str, ToUpper };
}
```

That second method there will give you a new String struct with all the function pointers set so you can use it.

Call it like this:

```
someString.ToUpper(someString)
```